# how to create multiple single threaded subscribers for a spring publishsubscribe channel

Tags: spring-integration

I have a spring integration publish subscribe channel.
Now, i create a subscriber to this channel, when ever a user logs in. so if there are 10 users, there will be 10 subscribers.

i want all these subscribers to be single threaded. is there any way to achieve that. please advise. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you configure a `PublishSubscribeChannel` with an executor, each subscriber will get its copy of message in a separate thread from that executor. If your subscriber flow does nothing with thread, all the steps are going to be performed in that thread.

This is not good practice to spawn as many thread as you have subscribers. Now imaging you going to have 1000 or even million...

It is better to configured `PublishSubscribeChannel` with a reasonable `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and let subscribers to compete in them rather than see how your system is dead because of too many threads.

Comment: Thanks for the response. i tried adding the executor. now if i have one consumer, and there are 2 messages published on the channel, each message is being handled by a different thread. i want this to be single threaded, so that the message are processed in sequence for each consumer.

Comment: Consider to add a `FluxMessageChannel` in the beginning of each consumer flow. This way independently of message source thread, the flux is going to be consumed only from the subscriber thread.